# Update a Data according to the Year

Tags: mysql

my table

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | Y2013 | Y2014 | Y2015 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |     1 |     1 |     1 |
|  2 |     1 |     1 |     1 |
|  3 |     1 |     1 |     1 |
|  4 |     1 |     1 |     1 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
```

fiddle : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2e2e/1

Here I am trying to delete/update a record according to the Year. If a record is deleting in Y2013, from that year to rest of the year should be updated to '0'.

eg: (ID-2) If a record is deleting on Y2014,  that year and next following years should be updated to '0', but the years before Y2014 should be maintain '1'.

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | Y2013 | Y2014 | Y2015 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |     1 |     1 |     1 |
|  2 |     1 |     0 |     0 |
|  3 |     1 |     1 |     1 |
|  4 |     1 |     1 |     1 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
```

Pls help

Answer (score 0):

Having the years as rows is not a good idea.  There is no (simple) way in MySQL to do comparison via column names.  The resulting table can be achieved by this query:

```
UPDATE myTable SET Y2014 = 0, Y2015 = 0 WHERE ID = 2
```

However it seems like you want a more dynamic version.  In that case, it either has to be done at the application level or you have to update your table to have more rows (with `id, year` as columns).  Then you can compare to IDs and years and delete rows of inactive years.

Comment: Thanks my friend. Actually I am not looking for a single update query. Is it possible to do it dynamically?

Comment: @user2594154 as I explained in my answer it is not since you have to know the column names ahead of time.  The only solution is to change the table structure so you can inspect row contents and compare to that instead.